# hp pavillion a1630n wont boot after ram upgrade

Tags: boot, memory, bios, cmos

would really appreciate some help with this:

I added 2gb ddr2 ram to an old pavilion a1630n for the 4gb max amount. After adding the new ram, the computer will only occasionally boot into windows. Most of the time it just loads to a blank screen, no mouse. I can get the computer to boot 100% of the time by clearing cmos.

All of the above holds true for any amount or combination of the above ram sticks, the two new ones or the two old ones. Both are the same voltage, clock and frequency and have the same markings under the specs.

Can anyone think of what might be causing this and how I could fix it? The only thing I can think of that I have not tried is a bios flash, but how would I do that on a computer this old?

Comment: Need more information on this one.  For instance, when you took out the upgrade and went back to the original configuration did it work again?

Comment: It did not work when I went back to the original configuration

Comment: "Can anyone think of what might be causing this and how I could fix it?" -Sounds like a hardware issue to me.  "The only thing I can think of that I have not tried is a bios flash, but how would I do that on a computer this old?" - Same way when it was new, go to the hp website, and download the firmware

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the recommendations. Unfortunately because the computer is over 10 years old, drivers, bios versions, and flash instructions are no longer available through hp. I did find a bios version but no information on flashing and there are no sections of the bios that mention this.

Comment: Hardware would seem strange because everything was working without a problem up until the moment I put the new ram in. If anyone has any input as to why this could be the case I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The problem with RAM is that you can zap it if you're not careful.  The whole original configuration thing could be a clue in that regard.  So let me ask a different question.  You say it won't boot.  Does that also mean you can't get into the BIOS?  And if you can, what does it tell you about RAM?  (Also, for a 10-yr-old computer, the cmos battery is always suspect.  If that fails you may get nothing no matter what you do with the RAM.)    So my Q to you is:  can you get the BIOS up on-screen?

Comment: I cannot get into the bios if it boots into a black screen with fans running and all other things appearing normal. I can get into the bios and OS though every time if I clear cmos. If I dont clear cmos, I can usually get into the bios and os on every second boot if I power down totally first. After doing this all four ram slots show up correctly and show the same frequency.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The computer now seems to be working with the 2g of the new ram only, havent tried the original with it for 4g... not sure if I want to risk it as I don't understand what caused the issue. This is very amusing. If anyone has any thoughts on why I'd love to hear, but for now I suppose this is resolved?